# Linux, Print all lines in a file, NOT starting with

Tags: linux, printing, awk, grep

I would like to print the contents of a file, but all lines starting with # I want to ignore. I was trying some stuff with grep and awk, but it kept printing the whole file, or just printed the lines starting with #. I you could give me a push in the right way, or a grep/awk command that would print anyline in the file that does not start with #.

Comment: `grep -v "^#" file.txt`

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60994/how-to-grep-lines-which-does-not-begin-with-or

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the `-v` option of `grep` to negate the condition:

```
grep -v '^#' file
```

Comment: What about if there are leading blank spaces at beginning of line, before the `#`?

Comment: @Sigur: `'^[[:space:]]*#'`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `!` operator:

```
awk '!/^ *#/ { print; }'
```

This negates the result of the match. I also included lines that start with spaces and then #, but you can tailor the regex how you like.

Answer (score 4):

You could use grep to exclude all lines that begin with `#` using the `-v` option

```
grep -v '^#' filename
```

If you're a fan of `sed`:

```
sed '/^#/d' filename
```

Comment: Two good examples.  But, in the sed example, you don't need the `.*` part.

Comment: @cmevoli - yes point taken, since the presence of the # at the beginning of the line is enough for the delete command :)

Answer (score 3):

This would also leave out lines with whitespace before the `#` :

```
awk '$1!~/^#/' file
```

or

```
grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*#' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the grep PCRE way,

```
grep -P '^(?!#)' file
```